# Buildout : entry point not found (creating my package)

Tags: python, buildout, entry-point

I'm trying to create an application base on buildout. I would like to use the a package as a recipe for buildout, but buildout can't find the final recipe.

Name of the package : `MyModule.recipe.mymodule-0.1-py2.7.egg` (in the develop eggs).

My recipe is (in the package) at : `MyModule/recipe/mymodule/__init__.py:Recipe`

Here is the `setup.py` in the root directory of my package :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

entry_points          = {'zc.buildout': ['default = MyModule.recipe.mymodule:Recipe']}

setup(
    name                    = 'MyModule.recipe.mymodule',
    version                 = '0.1',
    author                  = 'My Name',
    author_email            = 'my.name@domain.com',
    packages                = find_packages(),
    namespace_packages      = ['MyModule', 'MyModule.recipe', 'MyModule.recipe.mymodule'],
    include_package_data    = True,
    install_requires        = ['setuptools'],
    zip_safe                = False,
    entry_points            = entry_points
    )
```

Here is a tree in the root directory of my package :

```
.
├── MyModule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── recipe
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── mymodule
│           └── __init__.py
├── README.txt
└── setup.py
```

My buildout configuration :

```
[buildout]
develop +=
    develop-eggs/MyModule.recipe.mymodule-0.1-py2.7.egg
parts =
    mymodule
[mymodule]
recipe = MyModule.recipe.mymodule:Recipe
engines = ${engines:eggs}
binary = ${buildout:directory}/bin/myexec
```

Buildout is returning this error, which is pretty anoying :

```
Installing 'MyModule.recipe.mymodule'.
We have the best distribution that satisfies 'MyModule.recipe.mymodule'.
Picked: MyModule.recipe.mymodule = 0.1
Could't load zc.buildout entry point Recipe
from MyModule.recipe.mymodule:
Entry point ('zc.buildout', 'Recipe') not found.
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section lgsm.
  Initializing section lgsm.
  Loading zc.buildout recipe entry MyModule.recipe.mymodule:Recipe.
```

I tried to set the configuration as `recipe=MyModule.recipe.mymodule`, but this doesn't work too (same error, with "default" instead of "Recipe"). Do you have any idea of how to solve this issue ?

Note: i think i don't have the right keywords to find my answer on google. I searched a lot on the buildout "documentation", and i looked a lot on the plone documentation / implementation. Don't know where i can find my answer, so if you have a real documentation on buildout, please tell me where i can find it :)

Comment: The "default =" is the right version. One additional thing you might check: is setuptools installed globally? Somehow setuptools' entry points mechanism seems to require a global installation (or a virtualenv). I'm not sure, but I *did* have problems with buildout and entry points a few weeks ago and I seem to remember something like this...

Comment: Additional comment: normally a develop-eggs statement lists the *directories* (with a `setup.py` in them) of the packages you want to develop, not `*.egg` files. Perhaps this is the cause of the error?